# MySQL Query (change SELECT to DELETE)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    F.ID,
    F.REF1,
    F.REF2
FROM FRIENDS F
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A1 on A1.id = F.REF1
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A2 on A2.id = F.REF2
WHERE A1.WEB_IP = A2.WEB_IP;
```

I'm trying to change it to a DELETE command instead of SELECT. Somehow its now working.

Query which does not work:

```
DELETE FROM FRIENDS WHERE LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A1 on A1.id = FRIENDS.REF1
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A2 on A2.id = FRIENDS.REF2
WHERE A1.WEB_IP = A2.WEB_IP;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use:

```
DELETE friends
FROM frineds 
     LEFT JOIN accounts a1 on a1.id = friends.ref1
     LEFT JOIN accounts a2 on a2.id = friends.ref2
WHERE a1.web_ip = a2.web_ip;
```

You may find this reference [useful](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=6)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to delete the rows corresponding to ids returned by a query:

```
DELETE FROM FRIENDS
WHERE ID IN (SELECT F.ID FROM FRIENDS F LEFT JOIN ...)
```

Here is a second solution that is more readable and more performant (use of jointure directly from the `DELETE` statement instead of using a subquery):

```
DELETE F
FROM FRIENDS F
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS A1 ON A1.id = F.REF1
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS A2 ON A2.id = F.REF2
WHERE A1.WEB_IP = A2.WEB_IP
```

This second proposition use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` to optimize the query. You're looking for friends that are linked by `REF1` and `REF2` with the same `WEB_IP`. The use of `LEFT JOIN` is useless in this situation.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ["double from"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) syntax:

```
delete from f
from friends f
left join accounts a1 on a1.id = f.ref1
...
```

Comment: This does not handle the same information from the select, nor does in conform to http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=6

Comment: I tried this before, somehow its now working with this query.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: The article you link omits the optional `from` after `delete`.  Both versions work fine.

Comment: `If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table:` and then the syntax shows this query should work.. I would remove the first from just because its slightly confusing to read +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to leave out the `FROM` when specifying the tables in the join you are going to delete from.  To me this makes it easier to not confuse the traget tables for deletion with the join.  IN your case that would look like:

```
DELETE friends, a1 /* leave off a1 if you only want to delete from friends */
FROM friends
LEFT JOIN accounts as a1
  ON a1.id = friends.ref1
LEFT JOIN accounts as a2
  ON a2.id = friends.ref2
WHERE a1.web_ip = a2.web_ip;
```

You might also consider getting in the (IMO) good habit of putting MySQL keywords in uppercase and schema objects in lower case. I certainly helps make the query easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that exact select in a subquery for your delete statement

```
DELETE FROM `friends` 
WHERE `ID` IN 
(   SELECT `ID`
    FROM `FRIENDS` F
    LEFT JOIN `ACCOUNTS` A1 on A1.`id` = F.`REF1`
    LEFT JOIN `ACCOUNTS` A2 on A2.`id` = F.`REF2`
    WHERE A1.`WEB_IP` = A2.`WEB_IP`;
)
```

Comment: While this would in fact work, be cautious in using subselects as it could negatively impact performance (though sometimes it is better than join depending on factors such as table size, indexes, etc.).

Comment: @MikeBrant yes exactly this could be a better performing query or less depending on a lot of factors.

Comment: Yes. Generally it is a good rule of thumb to avoid a subselect, but if you we joining two or more large tables and you expect your filtering condition to drastically reduce the record set down to a handful of items, the subselect could improve performance.